# Join Table with Unnested Array in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a table of contacts and a study to with which they are associated. Now I am being passed an array of integers, representing `contact_id`. I need to join the current table of contacts with an unnested array of ids and delete the record if the unnested integer matches `contact_id`.

I have this so far

```
SELECT cvs.contact_id, cvs.study_id 
FROM study.contacts_vs_studies AS cvs
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT UNNEST('{1,2,3,4,68}'::INT[])) AS old_ids
        ON cvs.contact_id = old_ids.old_ids 
WHERE study_id = 6
```

This just returns all the available contacts for the study and nothing from the unnested array.

How can get a result of unnested array that matches select from existing table? TY

Comment: Which record exactly do you want to delete - the `conacts_vs_studies` one? You also mention a `contacts` table and presumably you also have a `studies` table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your query does what you want. But you cannot see it since you are doing a `left join` and not selecting anything from the unnested array.

Consider this sample data:

```
contact_id | study_id
---------: | -------:
         1 |        1
         2 |        2
         5 |        5
```

Now if we run the following query:

```
select cvs.contact_id, cvs.study_id, old_ids.old_ids
from contacts_vs_studies as cvs
left join unnest('{1,2,3,4,68}'::int[]) as old_ids 
    on cvs.contact_id = old_ids.old_ids
```

We get:

```
contact_id | study_id | old_ids
---------: | -------: | ------:
         1 |        1 |       1
         2 |        2 |       2
         5 |        5 |    null
```

Now you can see that the third record was not matched. To filter only on matching records, you can use an `inner join` instead of a `left join`.

```
select cvs.contact_id, cvs.study_id
from contacts_vs_studies as cvs
inner join unnest('{1,2,3,4,68}'::int[]) as old_ids 
    on cvs.contact_id = old_ids.old_ids
```

```
contact_id | study_id
---------: | -------:
         1 |        1
         2 |        2
```

Alternatively, if you want only non-matching records:

```
select cvs.contact_id, cvs.study_id
from contacts_vs_studies as cvs
left join unnest('{1,2,3,4,68}'::int[]) as old_ids 
    on cvs.contact_id = old_ids.old_ids 
where old_ids.old_ids is null
```

```
contact_id | study_id
---------: | -------:
         5 |        5
```

Answer (score 0):

> I need to join the current table of contacts with an unnested array of ids and delete the record if the unnested integer matches `contact_id`.

Sounds like you don't need a `JOIN` at all. Just write the `DELETE` command directly:

```
DELETE FROM study.contacts_vs_studies AS cvs
WHERE cvs.contact_id = ANY('{1,2,3,4,68}'::INT[])
  AND cvs.study_id = 6
```